Any ideas of why I'm getting this distorted output of my signal transformation circuit?

The red output on the scope is the amplified signal, and the orange is before amplification. I don't know why my signal is changing so drastically. I believe it might be due to the charge time on the capacitor, but I'm not sure.
Any help would be extremely appreciated. I'm trying to make improvements on an end-of-semester project. I'm aware the scope isn't grounded in this pic however I know that that's not the issue.

Without being able to see the entire circuit, any of the component values or part types, or even what the scales on the oscilloscope are, I'm not sure how you expect that we can provide any advice.


The scope display window is covering up part of your schematic.  Suggest post separate images for each.  2. What is the chip top left, is it a 555 timer?  3. What is waveform at pin OUT of this chip?  4. What are the op-amps, and why are pins 1 & 5 not connected?


i will edit the post,apologies.

Are you trying to generate a variable frequency square wave, and then filter it to get a sine wave? That will be problematic. If so, I will explain the problem in an answer.

Your schematic does not show where pins 4 and 7 (supply pins) of the op-amps are connected. They just go to short sections of horizontal lines. What does that mean?
